# Calculate a quantized color histogram in QT

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

i want to calculate a color-histogram of a hsv-image in c++. To create a 1D Histogram is very easy. But a 3D? For this i want not use external libraries beside QT. Is there a efficient way to do this?

Best Regards

Comment: Do it the same way you did the 1D.  There is nothing wrong with just an array.  There is no need to use QT or any other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a 3-dimensional array with n x m x p values. You might be better off with a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) depending on the values of n, m, and p. I don't know QT very well, but a quick search suggests that maybe [QTSoapArray](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsoap/qtsoaparray.html#details) would be a way to make a sparse array?